# Extract unique values to separate sheet based on values in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this has already been answered elsewhere but I just can't find it (or get what I've found to work for me).
Col "A" is a list of items with many duplicates.
In Col "B" I've placed an "X" for the items in Col "A" that I'm interested in.
What I'd like to get  out of this on a separate sheet is a list of unique values for only the items on the list where there's an "X" in Col "B".
Values only would be a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sheet has headers, the below might work for you.

If your sheet doesn't have headers, you could modify the code so that it inserts a row first.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FilterAndPasteUniques()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to whatever yours is called

    Dim lastSourceRow As Long
    lastSourceRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim toFilterIncludingHeaders As Range
    Set toFilterIncludingHeaders = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "B" & lastSourceRow)

    toFilterIncludingHeaders.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="X"

    Dim cellsToCopy As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set cellsToCopy = toFilterIncludingHeaders.Offset(1).Resize(toFilterIncludingHeaders.Rows.CountLarge - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not (cellsToCopy Is Nothing) Then
        cellsToCopy.Copy

        Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
        Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Change to whatever yours is called

        With destinationSheet.Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            .Resize(cellsToCopy.Rows.CountLarge, cellsToCopy.Columns.CountLarge).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End If

    sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: For future readers, I just realised I didn't need the `On Error Resume Next`. I could have instead checked if more than 1 row was visible (1 row would always be visible as the range reference contains headers) -- and then only proceed with the copy-paste on that basis. But no problem.